# Reading handwritten numbers using Deep Networks with MNIST Data in R Part2

Tags: r

I try to write a program based on Deep Networks to read handwritten numbers. I found a code in Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bso_5X7Zu4) which works there but it does not work for me. The problem is that the codes "predict_classes" and "predict_proba" according to the Error massage are deprecated and they are removed from tensorflow in version 2.6 (I have the latest version). The Error Massage suggests "predict() %>% k_argmax()" and "predict()" instead but they are not working for me. The code is:

```
    library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
str(mnist)
trainx <- mnist$train$x
trainy <- mnist$train$y
testx  <- mnist$test$x
testy  <- mnist$test$y

table(mnist$train$y, mnist$train$y)
table(mnist$test$y,  mnist$test$y)

# plot images
windows()
par(mfrow = c(3,3))
for (i in 1:9) plot(as.raster(trainx[i,,], max=255))
trainx[2,,]
windows()
hist(trainx[1,,])

# Analyzing Five
a <- c(1,12,36,48,66,101,133,139,146)
windows()
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for (i in a) plot(as.raster(trainx[i,,], max=255))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
# Reshape & rescale
trainx <- array_reshape(trainx, c(nrow(trainx), 784))
testx  <- array_reshape(testx,  c(nrow(testx),  784))
trainx <- trainx / 255
testx <-  testx / 255
windows()
hist(trainx[1,])
# One hot encoding
trainy <- to_categorical(trainy, 10)
testy  <- to_categorical(testy, 10)
head(trainy)

# Model
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>% 
          layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(784)) %>%
          layer_dropout(rate = 0.3) %>%
          layer_dense(units = 64,  activation = 'relu') %>%
          layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
          layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'softmax')
summary(model)

# Compile
model %>%
               compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy',
                       optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
                       metrics = 'accuracy')
# Fit model
history <- model %>% 
            fit(trainx,
                trainy,
                epochs = 30,
                batch_size = 32,
                validation_split = 0.2)

plot(history)
# Evaluation and Precition - Test data
model %>% evaluate(testx, testy)

# old version code: pred <- model %>% predict_classes(testx)
# the new version suggested by the Error Massage is:  
pred <- model %>% predict(testx) %>% k_argmax()

#table function below is not working
table(Predicted = pred, Actual = mnist$test$y)#table is not working

# old version code: prob <- model %>% predict_proba(testx)
# the new version suggested by the Error Massage is:
prob <- model %>% predict(testx)
cbind(prob, Predicted_class = pred, Actual = mnist$test$y)[1:5,]
```

Can you please help me with it?
You are welcome to suggest other codes. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error.

This example is found here https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/#mnist-example and documentation need to be updated?

```r
model %>% predict_classes(x_test)
Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_classes'
De plus : Warning message:
In predict_classes(., x_test) :
  `predict_classes()` is deprecated and and was removed from tensorflow in version 2.6.
Please update your code:
  * If your model does multi-class classification:
    (e.g. if it uses a `softmax` last-layer activation).

      model %>% predict(x) %>% k_argmax()

  * if your model does binary classification
    (e.g. if it uses a `sigmoid` last-layer activation).

      model %>% predict(x) %>% `>`(0.5) %>% k_cast("int32")

>
```

You can do something like this I think:

```r
model %>% predict(x_test) %>% k_argmax() %>% as.integer() %>% .[1:9]  

[1] 7 2 1 0 4 1 4 9 5
```

[image: x_test]

Comment: ok, but I get a warning massage. Is it important: Warning message:
In cbind(prob, Predicted_class = pred, Actual = mnist$test$y) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Comment: Maybe your problem is that I use `%>% 1:9` to print only first 9 first digits like on the image. Use this to have the same length as input: `model %>% predict(x_test) %>% k_argmax() %>% as.integer()`.

Comment: Yes. This works now. Thank you very much! My real problem now is to use the model to predict an image that I have made in Paint (namely, a figure of number 5).  I have formulated it in Part 3. Can you please look at it? Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195228/reading-handwritten-numbers-using-deep-networks-with-mnist-data-in-r-part3

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share how I solved this by digging through keras package functions.

```
pred <- model %>% predict(testx) %>% k_argmax() %>% k_get_value()
```

Comment: Aha, I will test it. Thank you very much